# Javascript/Jquery bind Label value to the value of a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

in an asp.net application,

I have a Label and a textbox.

I want the Label to always have the same value as the text box.

The text box value can be changed by the user or by other functions in the code, and I want the label to change with it.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#textboxId").change(function(){
   $("#labelId").text($(this).val());
})
```

Comment: Maybe mentioning the use of the `keyup` event to have real-time updates would be beneficial too

Comment: keyup I don't think it will raise when the text is changed by code

Comment: I meant in addition to the `change` event, just as a means to expand your answer for other viewers

Comment: @musefan On second thought there is no reason to update the label if the text hasn't changed...